# Entity Framework Code First Migration - Bad or Good

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a strange feeling when it comes about code first migration technology. First of all this is a concept which got its origins in technologies as Ruby on Rails. Not that I do have something against it, please do not get me wrong. What I am not sure about is that if the usage of Code First Migration is a good approach when it comes to high scalable enterprise applications which can include reporting, etc. Basically I am referring at situations where the database design, optimization plays a critical part in the general performance (denormalization, indexing, sharding, etc). My feeling is that Code First Migration brings a major overhead. Am I right, am I wrong? I would really like to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong.

EF Migrations has nothing to do with the way your database is designed.  It is only a one-time process that merely generates scripts against two versions of the database schema and figures out how to migrate from one to other automatically.

Migrations does not run when the app runs, it doesn't have any overhead or affect performance of the app.  It only works with the existing schemas as EF itself generates them.  In fact, this process is so generic, it isn't even specific to EF, Migrations can be used to migrate between any two schemas, whether they use EF or not.

As such, it has nothing to do with how the database performs.

The schema is controlled by EF itself, and is dependent upon how you map the database.  Yes, it's true that if you just let EF do all the work you might end up with a less than optimal schema, but you can fully control how it generates this by using Fluent Mappings.

Comment: The overhead at which I was referring is about the maintenance process when the db schema has to alter in order to improve performance. I never mentioned that migration runs when the app runs.

Comment: @MihaiH - I really don't understand your point then.  You have to alter the database one way or another, I don't see how automatically generating the scripts to do so is any more overhead than doing it manually.

Comment: In order to keep the migration in sync? You are aware the migration relies on the actual POCO and the relations between them.

Comment: @MihaiH - And?  So what?  You're not making your point clearly enough to understand what your actual issue is.

Comment: There is no issue actually. The only thing that I am skeptic is the benefits of migration.

Comment: @MihaiH - Before Migrations, EF would drop the table when you modified the model.  This lost any data that was in the table.  With Migrations, it will migrate the data to the new table as part of the process.  The other benefit is that it can automatically generate scripts to apply schema changes to your production database.